# The transaction log for database 'Name' is full.To find out why space in the log cannot be reused, see the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am getting following error while I am trying to insert 8355447 records in single insert query.i use sql-server-2008-r2.

INSERT INTO table

select * from [DbName].table

Please help me to solve.... Thanks

Comment: What does the `log_reuse_wait_desc` column in `sys.databases` say?

Comment: log_reuse_wait_desc set NOTHING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the disk space on the SQL Server as typically this occurs when the transaction log cannot expand due to a lack of free disk space.

If you are struggling for disk space, you can shrink the transaction logs of your application databases and also don't forget to shrink the transaction log of the TEMPDB database.

Answer (score 0):

Note:- Posting this as a separate comment as I am a newcomer to Stackoverflow and don't have enough points to add comments.

May be more than one options are available

1. Is it necessary that you should run this insert as a single
   transaction. If that is not mandatory, you can insert say 'n' no. of
   rows as a single transaction,  then next 'n' and so on.
2. If you can spare some space on another drive, created an additional log
   file on that drive.
3. Check whether you can clear some space on drive under consideration by moving 
   some other file to somewhere else.
4. If none of the previous options are open, shrink SQL transaction log files 
   with TRUNCATE_ONLY option ( release free space available at the end of log file to OS).
   dbcc sqlperf ( 'logspace') can be used to find out the log files with more free space in    it.

   USE' those databases and apply a shrinkfile, The Command is :- 
    dbcc shrinkfile (  , TRUNCATEONLY  )

   DBCC Shrinkfile details are available here [DBCC Shrinkfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms189493.aspx).
5. If you are not getting space even after that, you may have to do a rigorous shrink by re-allocating pages within the database ( by specifying a target size ) , details of this can be taken from the link provided.

Answer (score -2):

Well, clean up the transaction log. THe error is extremely clear if anyone cares to read it.

Comment: How to clean up the transaction log?

Comment: Read documentation. Start with switching to simple recovery model, then making a full backup.

Comment: i check [DbName], recovery model set simple .

Comment: Still that changes nothing unless you make the backup.